# scale the canvas in swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I try to create smth similar to pixel-art app
now I have some code to draw similar shapes, now I am trying to scale the canvas without changing the number of pixels inside it

```
        Canvas { context, size in

        for line in lines {

            let path = engine.createPath(for: line.points)

            context.stroke(path, with: .color(line.color), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: line.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
        }
    }
    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged({ value in
        let newPoint = value.location
        if value.translation.width + value.translation.height == 0 {
            //TODO: use selected color and linewidth
            lines.append(Line(points: [newPoint], color: selectedColor, lineWidth: selectedLineWidth))
        } else {
            let index = lines.count - 1
            lines[index].points.append(newPoint)
        }
        
    }).onEnded({ value in
        if let last = lines.last?.points, last.isEmpty {
            lines.removeLast()
        }
    })
    
    )
```

I tried to add  `frame(32,32)` to the Canvas, but then scaleEffect, scaledToFill and others does not work

Also I tried to use `.aspectRatio(CGSize(width:50, height: 50), contentMode: .fit)`, but this construction also increases the resolution of final image

so, how can I create the canvas with size, for example, 32x32, but scale it to the screen width?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The context you receive in your canvas has a `scaleBy:` method that lets you change the scale of the drawing without changing the size of the Canvas

Comment: @ScottThompson, OK, that is something

but scaleBy only "Changes the scale of the user coordinate system in a context" (C)
and lines, that I get soft line edges even in big scale values (like here https://ibb.co/vXKNckx - I set the scale to 200 and try to draw the 1-pixel line)

how can I get a "raster" result?

Comment: To get a raster result, you would have to do raster drawing... perhaps drawing your graphic into a bitmap context, creating an image, and scaling the image.